# Laravel/Vue.js - Timer

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, timer, vuejs2

I would like to ask for help.
I downloaded this project to learn how to use `Vue.js`:
https://justlaravel.com/vue-js-crud-laravel/

I wanted to do an automatic data download every *1sec* from the database. I got to the point that I can make a button to update this method but I can not do it on time.

The button on which it works:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="getVueItems()" id="name" name="name">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Refresh
 </button>
```

Automatic refresh that does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    getVueItems();
</script>
```

The `Vue.js` method:

```
  methods: {
  getVueItems: function getVueItems() {
  var _this = this;

  axios.get('/vueitems').then(function (response) {
    _this.items = response.data;
  });
  setTimeout(getVueItems(), 1000);
  },
```

Comment: Use setInterval `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello world"); }, 3000);` here you can find more infomation https://renatello.com/code/vue-js-polling-using-setinterval/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could provide you a solution which simulates your use case, by defining a method to fetch data from database (in my case an online API which provide the current date and time) and call that method in `created` hook, and by taking advantage of `setInterval` function we could get data every second.

Run this code snippet that i hope it could help you :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      now: 0
    };
  },
  created: function() {

    this.fetchTemp('https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/esi.dz/echo?user_content_key=ypoXRw1nVHj-h1VRDmh6TXSI1VpIPWW7Qo2n9El6RqoxAJ3v28nBI9bDY_4UAE0TQJ3pSozxpbTiRvFpmD8pvcTkGSnPAtgRm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_nRPgeZU6HP_B2BW4qWwVPUuHIcJ3mEdrfLIfNZsYUQi0c--vxV_3BX606CngcowlqSfFH8SSiqMPrUuXDMsd72r-P39_jlVDMh0BMLnMwXU02UuEHWiuob4ULL2SJgrtyBAf43AAwP8&lib=MwxUjRcLr2qLlnVOLh12wSNkqcO1Ikdrk');

    setInterval(() => {
      this.fetchTemp('https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/esi.dz/echo?user_content_key=ypoXRw1nVHj-h1VRDmh6TXSI1VpIPWW7Qo2n9El6RqoxAJ3v28nBI9bDY_4UAE0TQJ3pSozxpbTiRvFpmD8pvcTkGSnPAtgRm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_nRPgeZU6HP_B2BW4qWwVPUuHIcJ3mEdrfLIfNZsYUQi0c--vxV_3BX606CngcowlqSfFH8SSiqMPrUuXDMsd72r-P39_jlVDMh0BMLnMwXU02UuEHWiuob4ULL2SJgrtyBAf43AAwP8&lib=MwxUjRcLr2qLlnVOLh12wSNkqcO1Ikdrk');

    }, 1000);
  },

  methods: {

    fetchTemp(uri) {

      axios.get(uri).then((res) => {
        this.now = new Date(res.data.fulldate).toLocaleString();


      }).catch(err => {});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-axios@2.1.4/dist/vue-axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1> Now : {{now}} </h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```